# Download file to the client from server - jquerymobile/html5/c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am developing a html-5 application with jQuery mobile/c# and i am new to it.

I have to download a file (this file can be of any type say for example .dwg/.txt/.pdf/.doc/.xls/.mp3/.mp4..etc. ) to the client from the server when the user click on a link.  The file is created by a web service in a temp_file folder on the server dynamically.  How can i download this file into the client when the user clicks on the link...?

i tried to use the jquery.fileDownload.js plugin but it is failing if the viewer for the file type is not available.. (for example it downloads a .doc file but fails on a .dwg file)

any help in this direction is highly appreciated...

Comment: are you try a <a> download Attribute? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp

Comment: have not tried that.. i think it is not aligned with IE 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for those who tried to help... the issue is solved.. the problem was with the web server, where the MIME type entry was missing.. added that and it started working...